# Lightning Sync with multiple Office 365 Tenants?

Tags: lightning, sync, outlook, office-365

Is it possible to perform Lightning Sync between a **single instance of Salesforce** and **multiple Office 365 tenants**?

For example, I have a single SF instance, being used by multiple divisions of a company - each with their own domain and o365 hosted exchange servers: abc.com, xyz.com etc.

In Lightning Sync settings, I can only setup a single connection via OAuth2 or Exchange Service Account to an O365 tenant. There are no options to add further Service Accounts to connect to other tenants.

According to this Trailblazer article: [Lightning Sync additional domains to sync](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000337860&type=1&mode=1), last line (Limitations) - it appears that you can sync additional domains pertaining to the fact that they are all hosted on the same O365 tenant. Doesn't say much beyond that.

Has anyone tried implementing a similar use-case? Is my ask even possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Not exactly an answer but maybe it helps with the decision-making process, lightning sync will not be around forever anymore:
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000353407&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1

Comment: Hi Nina - yes, I saw that article as well. However, as of now, it looks like Einstein Activity Capture is being sold as a separate module. So absolutely no visibility into that.

Comment: One O365 tenant only. The Limitations in the note you reference does say that. A little more explicit is Q16 in https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000313684&type=1&mode=1